# Frontend-editing broken when text contains internal links

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.7.x

We are using TYPO3 8.7.19 with the extension frontend_editing (Version: 1.4.0) and CoolURI. We still use css_styled_content.

When editing a content element in the frontend with the „frontent-editing bar”, e.g. text I get an error, but only, if it contains an internal link.
The changes are not saved. It crash with:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1460629247: No valid handlers found for type: unknown | TYPO3\CMS\Core\LinkHandling\Exception\UnknownLinkHandlerException thrown in file /usr/share/typo3/typo3_src-8.7.19/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/LinkHandling/LinkService.php in line 163. Requested URL: https://www.mysite.de/typo3/index.php?ajaxID=%2Fajax%2Ffrontend-editing%2Fprocess&ajaxToken=--AnonymizedToken--&page=123
```

There is a [bug report](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/frontend_editing/issues/305)  and a suggested [solution](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/frontend_editing/issues/305#issuecomment-428728766) für TYPO3 9.5.x and a [solution](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/scw_bihlmaier/5ezpaB) for TYPO3 8.7.x

Unfortunately, I don't know how to realize that solution for my system, cause

1. wee use coolURI but not the required realurl-xtension.
2. I don't know where to add the suggested code

Any hints for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been [solved](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/frontend_editing/commit/f476b651406ca94768388e16be8d453fdaeeffc1) by the author of frontend_editing:

Add in typo3conf/ext/frontend_editing/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts

```
# Prevent links from being parsed to FE url
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.a >
```